# simple_form, bug with :has_many :through relation?

Tags: activerecord, has-many, simple-form

I have 3 models like these:

```
class CertificatorBtwInstructor < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :certificator
    belongs_to :instructor
    # other code ...
end

class Certificator < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :btw_instructors, :class_name => "CertificatorBtwInstructor"
    has_many :instructors, :through => :btw_instructors
    # other code ...
end

class Instructor < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :btw_certificators, :class_name => "CertificatorBtwInstructor"
    has_many :certificators, :through => :btw_certificators
    # other code ...
end
```

on my Instructor new form I have setting:

```
= simple_form_for( [:cm, @instructor], :html => { :class => "fAdm" } ) do |f|
    = f.object.errors
    - others fields ...
    = f.input :certificator_ids, :required => false, :collection => Certificator.choices_relation_select, :input_html => { :multiple => true, :size => 12 }
    %div.row.buttons
        = f.button :submit
```

then, when i submit the form without select any Certificator from the 'certificator_ids' input collection, the new record is created without problem.
But, when I choose any item on the 'certificator_ids' input collection, an error appear (i visualize it with the = f.object.errors ), and the error is this:

```
{:certificators=>["is not valid"]}
```

but on my form i haven't setting the field 'certificators', so I don't undestand why they got this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
<%= f.association :certificators, :as => :check_boxes %>
```

this will show to you all your certificators on check boxes, you should take a look at this
https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form
and this

http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many